# Invoking apply() on a matrix iterates through elements not rows?

Tags: r, apply

Consider a 2-column matrix `enum`:

```
Browse[2]> class(enum)
[1] "matrix"
```

Here is the contents of `enum`

```
Browse[2]> enum
                  x
pregnant  1   6.000
glucose   2 148.000
diastolic 3  72.000
skin      4  35.000
insulin   5   0.000
bmi       6  33.600
pedigree  7   0.627
age       8  50.000
```

The intention is to iterate through the rows: the attempt to do so is:

```
apply(enum, function(y) {
```

where `y` would represent one row at a time.

However `y` is becoming a single element instead of an entire row:

```
Browse[2]> y
[1] 1
```

Why was the iteration by `apply`  broken down into a single  list instead of a list of lists ?

Comment: It's not clear from your code what you're trying to do using `apply`. The second argument to `apply` should be the margin (1 = rows, 2 = columns, c(1, 2) = both, or a character vector if the dimensions are named).

Comment: ah ok - i *missed* that parameter - and `R` extracted it from the `tuple` ! Joys of dynamic typing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not specified the `MARGIN` argument of apply which must go before your function declaration.

Example:

```
set.seed(5)
enum <- matrix(data=c(1:5, runif(5)*100), ncol=2)
apply(enum, 1, function(y) { print(y) })
```

Output:

```
> apply(enum, 1, function(y) { print(y) })
[1]  1.00000 20.02145
[1]  2.00000 68.52186
[1]  3.00000 91.68758
[1]  4.00000 28.43995
[1]  5.00000 10.46501
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]
[1,]  1.00000  2.00000  3.00000  4.00000  5.00000
[2,] 20.02145 68.52186 91.68758 28.43995 10.46501
```

Comment: It is **very** interesting that `R` extracted one of the elements of the matrix to supply the `margin` argument. Why not just throw an error ..?